# Configuring hosted build server on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Could someone give me a good article/video/website where I can learn how to set up the hosted build server to pick up our files from the VSTS repository, build the app and publish it to Azure WebApp?

We even hired a consultant but it's not working and I feel it's time we learn this and handle it ourselves.

Comment: Sounds like you hired consultant of dubious quality! You can find plenty of info online, especially on http://visualstudio.com

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the steps here:

[Build and deploy your ASP.NET 4 code to an Azure web app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnet4-to-azure)

[Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core RC2 app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure)